# SQLScriptPreparer NullPointerException

Tags: orm, intershop

We have successfully executed the DatabaseTablesPreparer and inited the tables in the DB, but when we try to init the indexes on the table with SQLScriptPreparer, we get the following exception:

ES1 dbinit [] [] com.intershop.platform.cartridge.internal.CartridgeImpl [] [] [] [] "main" Neither Ivy descriptor nor cartridge properties found for cartridge 'app_core_a1'! 
ES1 dbinit [] [app_core_a1:Class1 DatabaseIndexesPreparer [hr/a1/core/dbinit/scripts/dbindex.ddl] Version:null] com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseIndexesPreparer [] [] [] [] "main" [core] Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.SQLScriptPreparer.getCommand(SQLScriptPreparer.java:158)
        at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.SQLScriptPreparer.process(SQLScriptPreparer.java:353)

We had the similar problem with DatabaseTablesPreparer (Cartridge was null), and we solved it by adding cartridge.properties file, but now we are getting the same error ("Neither Ivy descriptor nor cartridge properties found for cartridge 'app_core_a1'") even though the cartridge properties file is defined.

There are the lines in decompiled preparer code where the null pointer exception occurs:

```
getCartridge().getVersion() + (getCartridge().getBuild().isEmpty() ? "" : new StringBuilder().append(".").append(getCartridge().getBuild()).toString()) };
```

This is the preparer from dbinit.properties:

```
Class1  = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseIndexesPreparer \
          hr/a1/core/dbinit/scripts/dbindex.ddl
```

And this is the dbinit command we are executing:

```
dbinit.bat --exec-id=app_core_a1:Class1
```

DatabaseTablesPreparer from the same cartridge, defined in the same dbinit executes successfully.

Comment: Can you check if a "build" property exists within the file similar to a 'version' property?A NPE should happen only if _getCartridge().getBuild()_ returns _NULL_.

Comment: There is no property values in [cartridge].properties file. I'm not quite sure I understand. In which file should I look for the "build" and "version" properties?

Answer (score 3):

Problem was fixed by publishing cartridge. It seems that ivy descriptor was deleted and it had to be republished.